# console error output not showing the line with the error

Tags: python, django

Please I really need help, I do not know what could be going on in my program, initialy if there was an error it just simply point where an error is in
my code  e.g.

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\python_files\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\python_files\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\management\commands\runserver.py", line 75, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\python_files\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\python_files\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\python_files\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\python_files\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\python_files\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 408, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\python_files\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\python_files\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\python_files\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\python_files\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in
 urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\python_files\hospital_project\urls.py", line 61, in <module>
    url('residence/', include('hospital_project.residence.urls', namespace="residence")),#dashboard for residence
  File "C:\python_files\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\python_files\hospital_project\residence\urls.py", line 36, in <module>
    url(r'pharmacy1',  views.pharmacy1,  name="pharmacy"),
AttributeError: module 'hospital_project.residence.views' has no attribute 'pharmacy1'
```

from the above error it can be seen that the error is at file `C:\python_files\hospital_project\residence\urls.py` line 36

This has been the normal for a long time since I have been using python. But suddenly I discorvered that the output changed.
Instead of giving me the specific line in the file where the problem exist. It prints out the whole code in the pythong file onto the console.
See an example below.

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 1081, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 925, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 672, in format
    record.exc_text = self.formatException(record.exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 622, in formatException
    traceback.print_exception(ei[0], ei[1], tb, None, sio)
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\traceback.py", line 103, in print_exception
    for line in TracebackException(
  File "C:\software_development\python\venv\lib\site-packages\trio\_core\_multierror.py", line 393, in traceback_exception_init
    traceback_exception_original_init(
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\traceback.py", line 523, in __init__
    self._load_lines()
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\traceback.py", line 535, in _load_lines
    self.__context__._load_lines()
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\traceback.py", line 535, in _load_lines
    self.__context__._load_lines()
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\traceback.py", line 535, in _load_lines
    self.__context__._load_lines()
  [Previous line repeated 6 more times]
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\traceback.py", line 533, in _load_lines
    frame.line
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\traceback.py", line 288, in line
    self._line = linecache.getline(self.filename, self.lineno).strip()
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
    lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
    return updatecache(filename, module_globals)
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
    lines = fp.readlines()
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 6781: invalid start byte
Call stack:
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 890, in _bootstrap
    self._bootstrap_inner()
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\software_development\python\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, i
n wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\software_development\python\venv\lib\site-packages\channels\management\commands\runserver.py", line 106, in inner_run
    self.server_cls(
  File "C:\software_development\python\venv\lib\site-packages\daphne\server.py", line 143, in run
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=self.signal_handlers)
  File "C:\software_development\python\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\asyncioreactor.py", li
ne 255, in run
    self._asyncioEventloop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1859, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "C:\Users\software_developer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "C:\software_development\python\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\asyncioreactor.py", li
ne 271, in _onTimer
    self.runUntilCurrent()
  File "C:\software_development\python\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\base.py", line 991, in
 runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "C:\software_development\python\venv\lib\site-packages\daphne\server.py", line 290, in applica
tion_checker
    logger.error(
Message: 'Exception inside application: %s'
Arguments: (UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8', b'import re\r\nfrom django.db.models import Count, Avg\r\nfrom django.shortcuts import render, redirect\r\nfrom django.http 
import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, StreamingHttpResponse\r\n\r\nfrom django.urls import reverse...................the rest of the output are just my code
with \r \n \t included allover
```

please what could be going on and how can I get the program to produce error.
I would really appreciate any help thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first line of your log tells that it's a problem with `emit` method in `logging` python library. So the problem is that `logging` cannot properly emit the message to your terminal. The reason is at the bottom:

```py
File "C:\software_development\python\venv\lib\site-packages\daphne\server.py", line 290, in applica
tion_checker
    logger.error(
Message: 'Exception inside application: %s'
Arguments: (UnicodeDecodeError('utf-8', b'
```

So the site-package `daphne` which is probably a Django dependency has a problem logging the message because the `Arguments` that it tries to logs cannot be decoded to `UTF-8`.
From this traceback and without the actual code it's hard to say what's the exact reason, but if I were you I'd just run the code with the debugger, execute code line by line and check where the issue is.
You know which file causes the problem, because as you wrote the entire content of the file is logged.

You should be cautious what do you actually log. Do you log some user input data? Some contents of DB which you can't exactly predict? Can there be any special, non UTF-8 characters?